REST API call through custom policy receives all fields in sign-up form
I'm trying to build a sign-up flow where a user needs to fill in a confirmation number and their email address which gets submitted to an API for validation. If the combination matches a record in a database behind the API, then the user is allowed to register.
Although I got this flow to work, the API receives all fields part of the sign-up form, including the password fields. For obvious reasons I don't want these to be submitted to the API, and I can't figure out how to prevent this from happening.
I've followed the following guide to build the flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
As I understand it, only the InputClaims as configured in the "REST-ValidateProfile" TechnicalProfile are meant to be included in the API request body, which should be email, confirmationNumber and userLanguage.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
My TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml currently looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="MYTENANT.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://MYTENANT.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>MYTENANT.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkLocalization</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="confirmationNumber">
        <DisplayName>Confirmation Number</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Your confirmation number</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="role">
        <DisplayName>Advisor Role</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="userId">
        <DisplayName>Advisor User ID</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="userLanguage">
        <DisplayName>User UI language (used by REST API to return localized error messages)</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.2</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.2</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>


  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id"
              DefaultValue="ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource"
              DefaultValue="IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ValidateProfile">
          <DisplayName>Check web hook</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
            Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">URLHERE</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="KEYHERE" />
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="KEYHERE" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="confirmationNumber" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userLanguage" PartnerClaimType="lang"
              DefaultValue="{Culture:LCID}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="role" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <!-- Required to present the text box to collect the data from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="confirmationNumber" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateProfile" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>

The request to the API contains the following object raw values:
email=[value]&email_ver_input=[value]&newPassword=[value]&reenterPassword=[value]&displayName=[value]&givenName=[value]&surname=[value]&confirmationNumber=[value]&request_type=RESPONSE


Are you sure you are looking at the request to your API? The request to your API is made from the AAD B2C back-end so you can't see it in the browser.
